# roslaunch python

Tags: python, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to write a launch file for my python program. My program is named search.py and is located in `searching_tobot/src`. Here is my launch file so far :

```
<launch>

<group ns="robot0">
<node name="search" pkg="searching_tobot" type="search" output="screen">
  </node>
</group>

<group ns="robot1">
<node name="search" pkg="searching_tobot" type="search" output="screen">
  </node>
</group>

</launch>
```

However I have this error :

```
core service [/rosout] found
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [searching_tobot/search]: can't locate node [search] in package [searching_tobot]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [searching_tobot/search]: can't locate node [search] in package [searching_tobot]
```

And I can't find what I'm doing wrong. I tried replacing `search` by `search.py` with no luck

I'm used to do launch file with C++ executable and I'm a bit of a newbie with python on ROS and I couldn't find the answer and the wiki :S. Thanks a lot !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186510/roslaunch-python/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-07-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure if who have to use `search` or `search.py` (I believe the latter or both work) but one should work. My guess is your script file is not executable. Go to your `searching_tobot/src` and run

```
chmod +x search.py
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-14**:
You need to use whatever the file is called, so probably search.py.

**Comment by [marawy_alsakaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/31902/marawy_alsakaf/) on 2017-11-02**:
i tried this and it works, what is the reason behind this ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Also i don't know if this was your problem. But when you launch a node, the type parameter is the name of the executable to launch. Therefore since python does not need a compiler, and the executable is the own .py file. You need to just specify the .py file. This means something like this.

```
<node name="search" pkg="searching_tobot" type="search.py" output="screen">
```

I had a similar problem and this worked for me.

Hope this helps to anyone!

---

Originally posted by [donmrsir](https://answers.ros.org/users/19553/donmrsir/) with karma: 363 on 2016-01-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-25**:
Isn't this exactly what @Wolf answered (and @dornhege clarified)?

**Comment by [donmrsir](https://answers.ros.org/users/19553/donmrsir/) on 2016-01-26**:
Oh yes! sorry, I thought they refer to the sintaxis in the chmod call. Didnt read it carefully, my fault. Thank you for the note

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-26**:
No problem, don't worry. I was just wondering whether there was something in addition to what the other answer already provided.